# Illegal start of expression2

Tags: java

I am trying to write a method to capitalize words ending with an "s" in an arrayList

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {   

    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("speech.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void input() {
      while (input.hasNext()) {
        myList.add(input.next());
      }
    }

    public void capPlurals() {
      for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
        String element = myList.get(i);
        if (element.endsWith("s")) {
          System.out.println(element.toUpperCase());
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Test.java:12: error: illegal start of expression
       public void input() {
       ^

Comment: You can't create a method inside another method.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove those useless method declarations inside your main() method - as mentioned in the comments you cannot define methods inside other methods.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("speech.txt"));
        ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            myList.add(input.next());
            for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
                String element = myList.get(i);
                if (element.endsWith("s")) {
                    System.out.println(element.toUpperCase());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a method inside another method. Declare them outside the main and pass proper arguments.

```
    public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("speech.txt"));
        ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        addToList(input, myList);
        capPlurals(myList);
    }
    public static void addToList(Scanner input, ArrayList<String> myList) {
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            myList.add(input.next());
        }
    }
    public static void capPlurals(ArrayList<String> myList) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
            String element = myList.get(i);
            if (element.endsWith("s")) {
                System.out.println(element.toUpperCase());
            }
        }
    }
}
```